# How many bits does IEEE floating point uses in the normalization step?

Tags: matlab, floating-point, rounding, ieee-754

Using Matlab, for example. Suppose I give an input

```
a=0.1
```

The first step is to convert this string in the binary notation. In this step, how many bits the language takes into account to go to the step of rounding?

Could anyone suggest some further bibliography on this issue?

Consider double precision.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an IEEE 754 double, 53 bits of precision. Since 0.1 cannot be represented exactly, you'll have a random-looking pattern of bits set or unset over all 52 bits (leading bit implicitly one);

Comment: But the computer should use more bits,  otherwise all the rounding modes will be towards negative infinity. For instance, the round to nearest representation is 1 .1001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010 which means an adding one bit in the least significant bit. Any help?

Comment: Rules for IEEE arithmetic are very complicated, and it is easy to make an error in the last bit.

Answer (score 0):

Infinitely many. Per IEEE 754-2008, rounding from a decimal character sequence to a floating-point format uses “correct rounding” (clause 5.12.2, paragraph 3). Correct rounding converts “an infinitely precise result to a floating-point number” (clause 2.1.12).

Of course, the computer does not physically work with infinitely many bits, but the conversion is performed as if it did. That means a proper implementation of IEEE 754 must use an algorithm that gets a correct result.

I cannot speak to whether Matlab conforms to IEEE 754.